# Add data from a array to diffferents columns of a TableView javafx

Tags: javafx, tableview

I have a InfosPatient class which contains the informations of a patient:
His different names (birth name, official name...), different address (primary, work...), different phone numbers and other informations (sexe, birth date)

Here's is the class:

```
public class InfosPatient {
private Identity[] identities;
private String birthDate="";
private String sexe="";
private Adresse[] adresse;
private NumeroTelephone[] telephones;
private String numeroCafat="",numeroMed="";}
```

Here's the Identity class:

```
public class Identity {
private String prenom,nom;
private TypeNom typeNom;
```

TypeNom is an enumeration with 2 different values: Usuel (official name) and Naissance (birth name).

The address and phones classes are similar (with enumerations).

So my question is:

***How to add in a TableView row the different identities in different columns?***

I want to have a column with the birth name and another with the official name. Like this: [image]
One column with the official name and surname, a second with the birth name and surname.

Thank you for your help.

PS: To access a specific identity, I use this:

```
public Identity getIdentity(TypeNom typeNom) {
    for (Identity identity:this.identities) {
        if (identity.getTypeNom() == typeNom){
            return identity;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: The same way you would define the value of any `TableColumn`, set the appropriate [`cellValueFactory`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#cellValueFactoryProperty). Inside this factory you'd grab the correct `Identity` based on the `TableColumn` said factory is for.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, it's the first time I create a TableView so I don't know what to put in the setCellValueFactory method. Do you have a example please? I already did it with the birthdate: `birthDate.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("birthDate"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I find a solution:
I just needed to use a ReadOnlyStringWrapper:

```
TableColumn<InfosPatient,Identity> identiteUsuelle = new TableColumn<>("Nom usuel");
TableColumn<InfosPatient,String> prenomUsuel = new TableColumn<>("Prenom");
prenomUsuel.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(cellData.getValue().getIdentity(TypeNom.USUEL).getPrenom()));
TableColumn<InfosPatient,String> nomUsuel = new TableColumn<>("Nom");
nomUsuel.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(cellData.getValue().getIdentity(TypeNom.USUEL).getNom()));
```